# can we send request to server which forward that request to some other IP address

Tags: java, php, android

I am making an android application which can control the user's PC or laptop remotely. Is this possible that I send any request from the android application to the server and then server forward that request to the corresponding IP/Port address of user's. A software would also be running on user's system which will receive that request and then respond according to the request.

I just know very little about networks so don't know whether is this possible or not and if possible then how ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either:

1. Use some PubSub service (like Amazon SNS).
2. Write your own service, where clients would register for notifications and you would send those notifications to the server where clients are registered and this server would notify them.